# .click() not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a mobile application so I've shrunk my browser down to size just to quickly preview. But now when I test it on my mobile, taps are not being registered inside one div yet they are registered in another.

These are the two unresponsive buttons inside the div not registering clicks

```
<div id="loader">
    <img src="imgs/logo.png">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password"><br></br>

    <button id="signup-btn">Sign Up</button>
    <button id="login-btn">Login</button><br>

    <div id="fb_connect">
        <img src="imgs/fb_connect.png">
        <a href="#">Connect with Facebook</a>
    </div>
...
</div>
```

Here is the JQuery for those buttons

```
$("#login-btn").click(function (event) {
    $("#loader").hide('slide', {
        direction: 'down'
    }, 250);
    $("#application").fadeIn(250);
});

$("#signup-btn").click(function (event) {
    $("#signup").show('slide', {
        direction: 'down'
    }, 250);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z469k0n3/

Comment: Click event doesn't work on mobile, use 'touchstart'.

Comment: Then why's it working inside the other DIV, i'll give it a go though and let you know thanks

Comment: @abluejelly No they are inside

Comment: @JonathanZúñiga I've tried binding a touchstart but the same situation, works on desktop, not mobile.

Comment: Did you try this? `.on('click touchstart', function(`...

Comment: @JonathanZúñiga yes, same situation, works in desktop but not mobile.

Comment: Do you have jQuery UI module and jQuery correctly installed?

Comment: @JonathanZúñiga yes,  `<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-punch.js"></script>` these are in the head

Comment: Check here works: https://jsfiddle.net/jonathanzuniga/pwj9p2r7/ try with the latest versions.

Comment: @JonathanZúñiga I tried that fiddle on my mobile and it worked, implemented the same jquery into my project but no luck so i presume it's not a jquery problem...

Comment: @JonathanZúñiga For some odd reason, moving the jquery code into a script tag in the header fixed the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try jquery's mobile tap event rather than click to achieve more compatibility:

```
  $("#login-btn").bind( "tap", tapHandler );
  $("#signup-btn").bind( "tap", tapHandler2 ); 

  function tapHandler( event ){
    $("#loader").hide('slide', {
        direction: 'down'
    }, 250);
    $("#application").fadeIn(250);
  }

  function tapHandler2( event ){
    $("#signup").show('slide', {
            direction: 'down'
        }, 250);
  }
```

https://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/

Answer (score 1):

Try using jquery mobile's vclick event. This event handler simulates the "onclick" event handler on mobile devices.

```
$("#login-btn").on("vclick", event, function(event) {
    $("#loader").hide('slide', {
        direction: 'down'
    }, 250);
    $("#application").fadeIn(250);
});
$("#signup-btn").on("vclick", event, function(event) {
    $("#signup").show('slide', {
        direction: 'down'
    }, 250);
});
```

I hope this helps you!